# C macro that appends a string

Tags: c, macros

I need a macro that puts "**" before and after the string value, it should work someway like this:

```
#define M(x) <something>
puts(M("abc"))
```

Output:

```
**abc**
```

I've tried things like

```
#define M(x) "**x**"
```

but it doesn't work :/ 
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
#define M(x) "**" x "**"
```

It uses a feature that C compiler concatenates sequence of string literals.